# How can I map one property to multiple relations with entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am trying to use Entity framework 6.1 to build an application with a database first approach.

I am puzzled on how to build one-to-many relation while not using the default `Key` aka `Id` as the local property.

I have the following two models, first

```
public class UserToClient
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ViewClient")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Team")]
    public int DefaultTeamId { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual ViewClient ViewClient { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my second model

```
public class Team
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ViewClient")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ViewClient> ViewClients { get; set; }

    public virtual UserToClient UserToClient { get; set; }

}
```

Within my `UserToClient` model, I want to create one-to-many relation "One `UserToClient` has many `Team` "

With the end results, I want to be able to do something like this

```
using(var connection = new AppContext())
{
   var userToClients = connection.UserToClients
                                 .Include(x => x.Team)
                                 .Include(x => x.Teams)
                                 .ToList();


     //Do something with userToClients

     //Do something with userToClients.Team

     //Do something with each team

     foreach(var team in userToClients.Teams)
     {
         //Do something with 'team'
     }
}
```

If I was to write a query manually "outside Entity" I will do something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM [UserToClient] AS r
LEFT JOIN [Team] AS t ON t.ClientId = r.ClientId
```

**Problem**

The relation needs to point at a property called `ClientId` not the primary key `Id`.

Entity is currently generating a query like this and I want to be able t change `Id` to `ClientId`.

```
SELECT *
FROM [UserToClient] AS r
LEFT JOIN [Team] AS t ON t.Id = r.ClientId
```

It is important to understand that `Id` is the primary key, but in this case I want to join at a key that isn't the primary one.

How can I fix this issue?

**Attempt**

I attempted to solve this problem by overriding the `OnModelCreating` method in the context class like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()

                .HasRequired(x => x.UserToClient)
                .WithMany(x => x.Teams)
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.ClientId);

}
```

I need a way to tell the relation that the local propery is `ClientId` and not `Id`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe for this situation you need to also use the Fluent API to designate this type of relationship. A similar question with the answer is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22043285/5884242)

Comment: I am using database first approach. But I choose to write my own models reduce the around auto generated code. How would I do that?

Comment: The example I posted is a code first model. You use the fluent API to specify relations in the `DbContext.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder)` function